# Is it posible to interpolate convex hull in 2d space

Tags: interpolation

I have $n$ points (in this example $11$) and I need to interpolate them in such a way that I have a function $f(t) \rightarrow (R, R)$ where $t \in [0; 2\pi]$. It can be parametric curve, but I need to have a function.

[image]

Comment: Do you need smooth function, or just piecewise linear will fit?

Comment: I think that linear will be enough.

Comment: The convex hull does not necessarily include all the points. So do you want to interpolate the $n$ points or do you want to parameterize the convex hull?

Comment: @RahulNarain I want to parameterize points belong to convex hull (but function should return points between them).

Answer (score 2):

Order the points according to polar coordinates centered at the barycenter. Join consecutive points by a line segment. This gives you a piecewise linear curve using the angle as parameter.

Comment: See also [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan).